# Mint doesn't recognize my actual monitor

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, nvidia, monitors

Linuxmint 19.3 doesn't recognize my actual monitor, it acts as if I've got a 46" screen, which I don't have. Hence, it let me see just a portion of the entire screen.
I've tried to purge nvidia drivers (having big issues with dependencies) and reinstall them, but it didn't work.

That's the *Display* menu:
[image]

That's the portion of screen I can see:
[image]

Comment: Avolites Ltd doesn't seem to manufacture computer monitors, but various kinds of AV equipment. Is your computer directly plugged into the monitor, or is there some kind of signal switching/processing box in between? If the monitor (or a signal processing box, if applicable) has any kind of overscan/underscan setting, try switching it to "underscan" to see if it helps.

Comment: Yes, I've had to adjust the aspect of the TV (it is a TV, not a monitor): from 16:9 to "Point to Point".

Answer (score 0):

I've just had to adjust the aspect of the TV, used as a monitor, from 16:9 to *Point to Point*. I don't think that menu has the same entries for each TV. It solves my problem.

Comment: Yes. TVs often have multiple aspect ratio/zoom settings, and for using them as a computer display, you'll normally want whichever mode results in 1:1 mapping between the input signal at the display's native resolution and the actual pixels on the screen. Sounds like your TV's *Point to Point* is exactly that.